# Different font-weight for special characters

Tags: css, fonts, customization, difference, google-fonts

i have problem with font-weight, for "EN" languages it is working fine, but when I do the same thing with with my lang (SK) some characters have different font weight. Font is 'Open Sans'. When I try these chars in font.google viewer there is no problem. Actual font-weight is 300, on 400 there is no problem but I want it to be thin. The problem occurs on some Chrome(Mobile),Edge, IE. Any ideas?

[Open Sans on fonts.google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IZkq.png)

[Open Sans on my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYvyO.png)

link to page: thomaskovo.github.io/hotel-it/IT_Bussiness_Solutions/hosted_exchange_office_365.html

```css
body{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight:300;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
This is a testing text.
Mačka žena ťava šošovica
<hr>
Open this in Edge or IE
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post any of your HTML/CSS or better create a snippet?

Comment: It looks like the browser is using a different font for these characters as a fallback. Look it the "ĉ" characters in both examples and compare them. I think the font used on the website might be missing this character.

Comment: link to page https://thomaskovo.github.io/hotel-it/IT_Bussiness_Solutions/hosted_exchange_office_365.html

Comment: You only load the Latin glyphs for the font weight. You need to load all needed subsets. `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">` note: `subset=latin-ext`

Comment: See: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans?selection.family=Open+Sans the embed AND customize tabs.

Comment: @TomášKováčik On Google Fonts you can go to the customize tab, scroll down and check whatever glyphs you need (cyrillic, latin, greek,...)

Comment: I added a snipped of the problem, I used customize tab

Comment: @allcaps Thanx! That worked for me

Comment: I turend my comment into an answer. Please mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font used doesn't contain all glyphs. Due to font fallback, the missing glyphs fall back to some other font.

You only load the Latin glyphs. You also need to load subsets that contain the needed glyphs:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&amp;‌​subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
```

Note: `subset=latin-ext`.

I took this snippet form [fonts.google.com](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans?selection.family=Open%20Sa%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bns) on the embed AND customize tabs (bottom right).